# BizTalk 2013R2 & SQL SERVER - Timeout Errors caused by Connection Leaks

Tags: sql-server, biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

We've been receiving hundreds of errors on BizTalk 2013R2 recently (running CU 8);

> Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a
>   connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled
>   connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

I suspect these are being caused by Connection Leaks, but I'm not sure how to pin down the exact source.

I've tried querying with `SP_WHO2` to see how many/which connections are open, and can see a LOT of sleeping connections to our Biz server, but again, can't quite isolate them.
I can see which send port the issues occurring on, and I can see which called Stored Procedure via WCF-SQL is being rejected by the above error, but I'm now at a loss as where to go next.

As far as I'm aware, there's no unorthodox connections or adapters being used to call connections to the Biz server.
The only thing I can think of might be that the connections behind Typed Polling calls isn't being closed.

Should BizTalk be closing any WCF-SQL/WCF-Custom adaptor connections once its attempted connection?

Any suggestions on where to go next to isolate the source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was supposedly fixed in CU 7 for BizTalk Server 2013 R2, see [FIX: WCF-SQL adapter fails intermittently if AmbientTransaction is True or if ReceiveTimeout is not more than polling time plus time to query data from SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/help/4020017).

The workarounds implied in that article used to work to some degree before CU 7, e.g. set the ReceiveTimeout to a really large number. So try that.